# Applying several elements indexes from one array to another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I would like some help to solve a problem involving arrays.

I've tried some topics from stack overflow (np.where, sort) and didn't find how to solve my situation.

Here it is:

I've got two numpy arrays (A and B) of objects and both have the same dimensions (900,900,3).

The array A has specific elements as strings repeated several times with n indexes which are specified in a list. I need to know (search, collect, detail) these indexes and use them as reference to do some calculations regarding array B data (intergers/float).

As mentioned previously, the arrays are large. Can I do this through loops or some function?

Comment: Could you give use more info? What are exactly the strings you are looking for? Maybe also give access to a snippet of your data or all of it?

Comment: I have a list of strings that exist in the matrix A.
These strings are names of cities like: StringsA = [New York, London, Hong Kong, Dubai, ...., Seoul]

I need to know the indexes where the cities names are located in matrix A. Then, with this indexes, apply them as reference in matrix B to do sums (B contains floats).

Referencing all indexes that a address New York in A, I need to sum all the data from B having a single number as a result, for example. And for all the cities as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly use your 3D array of dtype object containing cities to index your 3D array of floats, e.g. :

```
np.sum(numbers[cities == 'New-York'])
```

With for example `cities` as:

```
np.array([[['Berlin', 'Paris'],
           ['New-York', 'Oslo']],

          [['New-York', 'Reykjavik'],
           ['New-York', 'Madrid']]], dtype=object)
```

and `numbers` as:

```
np.array([[[0., 1.],
           [2., 3.]],

          [[6., 7.],
           [4., 5.]]])
```

you would get `12.0` !

And then finally you could loop over the cities to get the different sums as:

```
for city in cities.flatten():

    print(city, ': ', np.sum(numbers[cities == city]))
```

which gives:

```
Berlin: 0
Paris: 1
New-York: 12
Oslo: 3
New-York: 12
Reykjavik: 7
New-York: 12
Madrid: 5
```